# Memory footprint minimization in Java EE 5, for classes, primitive data types and Strings

Tags: java, java-5, memory-optimization

Context is: Java EE 5.

I have a server running some huge app. I need to refactor the classes, so that their memory footprint is low (towards lowest possible), in exchange for CPU time (of which there's plenty).

I already know of ways to use bit operations to stuff multiple booleans, shorts or bites into an int (for example).

I'd need from you other optimization ideas, like, what do i do with Strings, what collections are better to use, and anything else that you happen to know.

Thx,
you guys rule!

Comment: You need to provide more detail on your goals and what you've done so far. When it comes to performance, you need measure and not guess where you need to tune things. You can use VisualVM for some simple memory profiling or a commercial tool such as YourKit.

Comment: well that's the thing. i don't really know how to measure memory usage consistently, or give more information. Anyway, what i've done so far was to replace Boolean's with boolnean's (but i'm thinking of switching back to Booleans (to use singleton instances). I've also transformed Strings to byte arrays, and dates to integers. Apparently though people like to flame noobs....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pdf about [memory efficiency in java](http://domino.research.ibm.com/comm/research_people.nsf/pages/sevitsky.pubs.html/%24FILE/oopsla08%20memory-efficient%20java%20slides.pdf) might be of interest to you.

Especially the standard collections seem to be huge memory wasters. But the first step before doing any micro-optimizations would be to profile your application, create heap dumps and analyze these.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to consider

- If you are done with an object and it will remain in scope, set it to null
- Use StringBuilder (or StringBuffer if you need thread safety) instead
  of concatenating Strings.

However, if your memory usage is such an issue it may be an architectural problem with the code.